# What is $H^0(X;G)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Let $X=\sqcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ be a topological space consisting of a disjoint union of path connected components and $G$ an abelian group. What is $H^0(X;G)$?**

In homology one gets using the augmentation map that $H_0(X;G)\cong\bigoplus_\alpha G$.

In cohomology I tried looking at a cochain $\phi\in S^0(X;G)$. It is a cocycle $\Leftrightarrow \delta(\phi)=0 \Leftrightarrow \phi$ is constant on the the path connected components of X. But I don't understand what $H^0(X;G)$ looks like.

What step am I missing to understand the zeroth cohomology group?

Comment: So you know what the cocycles look like which means you now need to quotient out by the coboundaries, but of course there are no coboundaries (besides 0) since the differential increases degree and you are in lowest degree. By definition, cohomology is cocycles modulo coboundaries, so you have your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$H^0(X; G)$ is the dual of $H_0(X; G) = \bigoplus_\alpha G$, hence $\prod_\alpha G$. This can be seen by explicitly computing the cocycles as you indicated, which are $G$-valued $0$-cochains that are constant on the path components of $X$, i.e., constant on $X_\alpha$. This is the direct product of the groups $G$ indexed over the path components. There are no nontrivial $0$-coboundaries because of degree reasons.